# HTML & CSS - Links doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have made a very simple website using HTML and CSS, I have added a few links as well but only one of the links actually work. There are 4 links in total and only the one at the bottom of the code will work. Please help. This is my HTML code:

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  border: 0;  font-size: 100%;  font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  font: 25px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ol,ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 1200px;
}

.faq {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 900px;
}

.shop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 580px;
}

.contact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 200px;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.hemsidan {
  background: #ffffff url(../images/hemsidan.png)no-repeat 50% 50%;
  height: 1389px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hemsidan"><img src="images/hemsidan.png" height="1389" width="1366" alt=""></div>
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="faq"><a href="http://pages.ebay.com/seller-center/faq/index.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li class="shop"><a href="https://www.blocket.se/">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I am very new to HTML and CSS so forgive me for the horrible coding, I just want the links to work.

Comment: Just copy/pasted your code and all the links work for me. What is the part not working for you?

Comment: Only "Contact us" works for some reason, all the other texts are unclickable

Comment: What is your problem actually, you don't wanna work rest of the 3 links but only "Contact"?

Comment: What? No, I want all links to work but Contact is the only one that works and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't any problem with the links. I suppose as you're positioning them as absolute in the container they are overlapping one over the other and what you are actually clicking is some div or element blank area.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
font: 25px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
.nav {
float: left;
}
.home { 
//position: absolute; 
//top: 173px; 
width: 100%; 
padding-right: 1200px;
}
.faq{
//position: absolute; 
//top: 173px; 
width: 100%; 
padding-right: 900px;
}
.shop{  
//position: absolute; 
//top: 173px; 
width: 100%;
padding-right: 580px;
}
.contact{
//position: absolute; 
//top: 173px;  
width: 100%;
padding-right: 200px;
}
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
.header {
text-align: center;
}
.hemsidan{
background: #ffffff url(../images/hemsidan.png)no-repeat 50% 50%;
height: 1389px;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hemsidan</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<header class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="hemsidan"><img src="images/hemsidan.png" height="1389" width="1366" alt=""></div>
<div class="centered">Centered</div>
<nav>
<ul class="nav">
<li class="home"><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="faq"><a href="http://pages.ebay.com/seller-center/faq/index.html">FAQ</a></li>
<li class="shop"><a href="https://www.blocket.se/">Shop</a></li>
<li class="contact"><a href="https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump">Contact us</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably right, I do have an image in the background and I'm trying to make the links overlap the background image. When I try to run the code you provided, the text doesn't show up at all because they're probably behind the image.

Answer (score 0):

Links are just overlapping as top value is given `173px` for all of them. Just change `top: 173px;` to some other value for each link or instead of padding-right just use "right" and "left" positioning.  or remove all these lines below.

```
.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 1200px;
}
.faq {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 900px;
}
.shop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 580px;
}
.contact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 173px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
```

You position each link as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your li elements are absolutely positioned over each other. This means that last li covers and blocks previous li-s.

Instead of absolute positioning and padding-rights do this:

```
.home { 
    display: inline-block;
}
.faq{
    display: inline-block;
}
.shop{  
    display: inline-block;
}
.contact{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(There is really no need for ul and li elements at all. Just put your links inside nav block and give them some padding)

Comment: When I do this, the background image will overlap the text/links and they won't show up at all.

Comment: Ok, for background image use css background-image on body or .container.

If you want to use real image, give your background image absolute position with z-index:10 and your nav relative position with z-index: 20.

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong, this is what happens: https://imgur.com/a/TJOTG

This is my code: https://pastebin.com/fBnTgYf0

Answer (score 0):

This is the sanitized code (As mentioned you were using position: absolute; for links which was leading to a click to other place but not on link)

```css
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hemsidan"><img src="images/hemsidan.png" height="1389" width="1366" alt=""></div>

  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="faq"><a href="http://pages.ebay.com/seller-center/faq/index.html">FAQ</a></li>
      <li class="shop"><a href="https://www.blocket.se/">Shop</a></li>
      <li class="contact"><a href="https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump">Contact us</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```